# Правильное произношение.

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте.   " Умереть от голода". "Умереть с голоду". "Умереть с голода"Какой из этих вариантов произношения данного суждения является правильным?   Какая область русского языка регулирует эту правильность.   Спасибо. С уважением, Юрий.

Comment: Здравствуйте Бойко Юрий.

1. Предложение "X умер от голода." похоже на предложение "X умер от рака поджелудочной железы.".

2. Предложение "X умер с голода." похоже на предложение "X умер с рака поджелудочной железы."

3. Предложение "X умер с голоду." похоже на предложение "X умер с раку поджелудочной железы.".

Answer (score 3):

" Умереть от голода"-норма письменного языка (§199. Выбор предлога
 речи); http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm - Р•_06)

"Умереть с голоду" - разговорный вариант, так называемый партитив (количественно-отделительный, родительный частичный падеж) - падежная форма,
 выражающая свойство частичности, отделения части неисчислимого, существует как фразеологизм.

"Умереть с голода"- ненормативно

Comment: Регулирует это грамматика, нормы управления

Comment: Умирать  с  голоду  можно  и  вполне  здоровому  человеку,  когда  очень  есть  хочется.  Умереть  от  голода  -  констатация  медицинского  факта.  А  умереть  с  голоду  -  это  как  стрелять  с  ружья.  Ненормативно,  но  встречается  достаточно  часто.

Answer (score 1):

1. Действительно, умереть от голода - норма, умереть с голоду - разговорный вариант. А вот почему именно так?
2. Чтобы разобраться, попробуем сравнить  варианты по значению приставок. В нашем примере родительный падеж выражает отвлеченное значение ПРИЧИНЫ, которое развивается на основе ОТЛОЖИТЕЛЬНОГО значения (основного для предлога ОТ). В Грамматике-80 указано, что предлог ОТ выражает активную причину, а предлог С - пассивную (обусловленную психическим/физическим состоянием действующего лица): плакать от радости, дрожать от холода, но: зачахнуть с тоски, устать с дороги. В то же время это объяснение не совсем понятно.
3. Тогда поищем другую версию. В нашем примере предлог ОТ - это основной (нейтральный) вариант. А какое точное смысловое значение имеет предлог С? Если обратиться к исходным пространственным значениям, то они различны, например: отойти от горы - съехать с горы. Почему же здесь произошло сближение?
4. Можно предположить, что разговорный вариант имеет ОБРАЗНО-УСИЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ значение и  связан с народно-поэтической речью. Сравним, например: отчего это вдруг - с чего это вдруг. В этих примерах именно предлог С кажется более активным, придающим действию своеобразное ускорение и экспрессию (выразительность).

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание разговорный вариант "помереть с голоду"!

Comment: А  чем  он  отличается  от  такого  же  разговорного  "умереть  с  голоду" ?

Comment: Да, собственно, "умереть" и "помереть" в данном случае синонимы. Хочу сказать, что я за разграничение лексики разговорной и литературной: "помереть с голоду" и "умереть от голода".

Comment: Так  они  и  разграничены  на  литературный  и  разговорный  варианты.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно,  интересно.  Такие  словосочетания  с  предлогами  ОТ  и  С,  указывающие  на  причину,  грамматически  различаются.    Вот  пары:  от  голода - с  голоду,  от  скуки - со  скуки,  от  горя - с  горя,  от  страха - со  страху,  от  смеха - со  смеху,  от  дури - сдуру.  В  двух  последних  случаях  словосочетания  с  предлогом  С  превращаются  в  устойчивые  выражения (  с  изменением  ударения  и  написания ) и  переходят  в  наречия.  И  в  первых  четырёх,  видимо,  тоже.  А  конструкция  с  наречием,  конечно,   обладает  большей  экспрессией.

Comment: Фразеология : *пухнуть с голоду*.  
> В. Я. Шишков. Угрюм-река. Ч. 1-4 (1913-1932)  
 ― Если начнешь **пухнуть с голоду**, на все согласишься.